# A rational matrix such that $A^{2017}=I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

> Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $A^{2017}=I_n$. Is it always true that $$A=I_n?$$

When $n \leq 2015$, I proved that this result must hold using the minimal polynomial and the fact that $2017$ is prime. I suspect that when $n \geq 2016$, this equality is not always true, but I can't find any matrix other than $I_n$ with that property, which also has only rational entries.

I also thought of an approach with eigenvalues, but since they are all complex roots of $2017$, I am not sure how to make use of them here.

Answer (score 5):

Consider any [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), corresponding to a permutation of order $2017$.  This will satisfy $A^{2017}=I_n$ and $A\neq I_n$.

For this example, we need any $n\ge 2017$, because $2017$ is prime.  For $n=2016$, see Lord Shark's answer.

Comment: I think I can prove the $2016$ case combining the previous argument with eigenvalues. Could you please provide more details if there is an argument which only uses polynomials?

Answer (score 5):

Take a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) for the polynomial $x^{2016}+x^{2015}+\cdots+x+1$.
It is in $M_{2016}(\Bbb Z)$ and satisfies $A^{2017}=I$.